# How do you get the world location of a UChildActorComponent?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm attempting to create a weapon for my ACharacter in UE4. The weapon is a UChildActorComponent with a child class of AWeapon. The trouble that I'm currently having is that when I want to fire the weapon, I'm unable to get a start location.

tl;dr - How can I get the world location of a UChildActorComponent? Everything I've tried returns x,y,z(0,0,0).

Comment: I'm guessing the ChildActorComponent has a local transform relative to the Character, but you should still be able to use ChildActorComponent::GetRootComponent()->GetComponentTransform() to get the Weapon's RootComponent's world transform.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to invoke:

```
MyChildActorComponent->AttachToComponent(GetRootComponent(), FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepRelativeTransform);
```